# How to get formatting to ignore potential formatting in text?

Tags: formatting

Sorry for the terrible title and the probably silly question.
Essentially I would like to display "\\server" as text in the pdf, however tex is taking the \\ as a return.

Thanks,

Comment: \verb!\\server!

Comment: `verb+\\server` or `\textbackslash\textbackslash server` ... for more i should see context of this, i.e.. provide small complete document which will demonstrate your problem,

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks so much for your quick help. Johannes_B's answer helped. My final code looks like `\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{section}{-1}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Type \verb|\\server| to access
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Final solution from [Adam's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393079/how-to-get-formatting-to-ignore-potential-formatting-in-text#comment976703_393079)]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\setcounter{section}{-1} 
\begin{document} 
  \begin{enumerate} 
    \item Type \verb|\\server| to access 
  \end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```